# Handling alignment in a custom memory pool

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to make a memory pool class that allows me to return pointers from within a char* array, and cast them as various pointer.  Very very simplified implementation:

```
class Mempool
{
     char* mData=new char[1000];
     int mCursor=0;

     template <typename vtype>
     vtype* New()
     {
        vtype* aResult=(vtype*)mData[mCursor];
        mCursor+=sizeof(vtype);
        return aResult;
     }
};
```

(Remember, it's not intended to be dynamic, this is just random access memory that I only need for a short time and then it can all be tossed)

Here's my issue: I know that on some systems (iOS, at least) a float* has to be aligned.  I assume the alignment is obtained via alignof(float)... but I can't ever be sure of the alignment of the initial char*'s allocation could be anywhere, because alignof(char) is 1.

What can I do to make sure that in my New() function, my mCursor is advanced to a proper alignment for the requested object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alignof(std::max_align_t)` will tell you the alignment required on your platform for standard functions like `malloc()`.  You should use that if you don't know what alignment requirements the users of your allocator will have.

Simply round `sizeof(vtype)` up to the nearest multiple of `alignof(std::max_align_t)` when you increment `mCursor`.

Or for perhaps a little more efficiency, increment `mCursor` as you do now, then round it up as needed when the user requests an allocation.  When allocating an object of size 2 for example, you know that 2-byte alignment is sufficient, you don't need the full `alignof(std::max_align_t)`.  You can use `alignof(vtype)` for this, to avoid wasted space if users allocate small objects next to each other.

As for this:

> I can't ever be sure of the alignment of the initial char*'s allocation could be anywhere, because alignof(char) is 1

You can be sure: `new char[N]` will always be aligned to at least `alignof(std::max_align_t)`.  But my second approach (pad when New is called) does not rely on this assumption.

Comment: I'd still add `static_assert(alignof(std::max_align_t) >= alignof(vtype), "Alignment requirements cannot be satisfied");` to the `New` function.

Comment: @fabian I agree that's a good idea if using my first approach (round up the same amount when advancing `mCursor`).  If using my second approach it becomes irrelevant.